# How to handle input files uniformly

Tags: perl

I have a program expecting input from stdin, OR from a mix of .log and .log.gz files. Here are the three types of calls I want the program to handle:

```
cat input.log | prog
prog < input.log
prog input.log input.log.gz
```

The program considers all input files as one. I was hoping to capitalize on ARGV to process all input uniformly:

```
while (<>) {
# process input
}
```

My goal is to process gz files in the same loop. How can this be done? I want to know how messy it is. If it is too bad I will handle gz separately.

I can only use core modules with Perl 5.8.8.

Comment: Poor you.. those limitations cripple Perl severely. `IO::Compress::Gzip` and `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip` are core since 5.9.4.. what reasons could there be to pin you to an ancient Perl interpreter without any CPAN modules?

Comment: I wouldn't consider trying to handle the gzipped files w/o module support.  You'd be forced into 'run `gzip -cd` and read its output' shenanigans; it is simpler just to make the invoker deal with decompression.

Comment: Don't like this requirement, complained about it but I have no control on it for now. All hope is not lost but that's another topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do that and get the shorthand benefit of the diamond operator.

- Because you're going to have to monkey with the input handle, you're going to need to `open` the files yourself.
- You might be able to use `@ARGV` for this, but you'll only get the easy handling if you reopen `*::STDIN` for these files.

  ```
  my $file = shift;
  if    ( !$file )           {} # use STDIN as is.
  elsif ( $file =~ /\.gz$/ ) { 
      open( ::STDIN, '-|', "gunzip $file" ) or die "Could not open: $!!";
  }
  else {
      open( ::STDIN, '<', $file ) or die "Could not open $file: $!!";
  }

  while ( <> ) { 
      ...
  }
  close STDIN;
  ```

Comment: am I reading this wrong? it looks like the gunzip is in the wrong else block.

Comment: @mattc: Yes, you are. It's assuming `gunzip` needs to be used if the file ends with a gzip suffix.